# Creating pokedex, having trouble adding image

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm creating a pokedex but in the process im having trouble adding an image. The only time it seems to work is when i pass it through the function show_image, but that only works when i use document.body. Im new to react so check my code and if you find anything useful that would work i appreciate it.

Edit: ignore the break tag(used it when adding different properties from pokedex), and ignore the function. i was just playing around with them to get an idea of different options.

```
import React from 'react';
import Data from './pokeapi_testex.js';

class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    var foo = document.getElementById("inner-screen");
    event.preventDefault();

    // function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
    //     var img = document.createElement("img");
    //     img.src = src;
    //     img.width = width;
    //     img.height = height;
    //     img.alt = alt;
    //
    //     // This next line will just add it to the <body> tag
    //     document.getElementById("inner-screen").innerHTML =
    // }

    var inputval = this.state.value.toLowerCase();
    var data_map = Data.forEach(function(i){
      if(inputval === i.name){
        foo.innerHTML = i.element_type + "<br>";
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form id="colored" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default NameForm;
```

Comment: Where is the component that contains `inner-screen` and why are you not adding the images in there?

Comment: @geraint inner screen is within another component, on a different js file. i referenced it here but since you mention it ill give it a go there and see what i can do.

Comment: @Geraint i have tried what you said but it doesnt work. do you have any possible ideas on the solution? it returns all info besides img